# how to repair Xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin.android

I have already install Xamarin Studio 6.0

Now I Want to install Xamarin.android for android apps development (because checkbox is disabled).

How I can modify this component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Microsoft Visual Studio for Mac now completely replaced Xamarin Studio. Last version of Xamarin Studio I had installed was marked as damaged or corrupted on my Mac so I just moved it into Trash and installed Visual Studio for Mac. After that I was able to install new versions of Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS et cetera.